# Avoiding XSS attacks when storing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xss

My site stores HTML that is generated by the user. Then of course this data is rendered on a web page. What are the best practices for rending the HTML and avoiding XSS attacks? Is stripping `<script>` and `<iframe>` tags enough? Will this cover all browsers? I heard of old browsers rendering HTML from weird encoding... how can I handle this?

I would like a general answer, not related to any languages or technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use libraries like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) especially their [whitelist-sanitizer](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) to prevent XSS.

In general, I think it is a better/safer aproach to use a **white list**, rather than filtering black listed tags. Besides, HTML should be avoided in the first place. Instead, some simple markup, like [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), should be used.

Comment: I know there are libs that do this, but I wanted a generic answer on what tags should be avoided and why, as I think this could serve a good reference for future users to understand XSS attacks.

Comment: What if a new tag is introduced that is XSS-capable? What if there is a tag specific to a single browser which you might disregard? What if somebody does `<div style="width:10000px;height:10000px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;" onmousemove="javascript:evil()">`? Basically every tag is dangerous unless you use a sophisticated filter whitelist.

Comment: Well, if you ask which tags should be blacklisted, I would say "all of them, but...", what means white listing. However, HTML should be avoided in the first place, if that is an option. (edited my answer to that respect).

Comment: From your link I found this: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html which is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Luca: nice read, but as I said, I would go with some lightweight markup instead of HTML. This has more atvantages than preventing XSS attacks. For example, when you want to render the given text to some other output format e.g. PDF. However, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you there is no way to safely do what you are asking. A crafty hacker will always be able to exploit a system that allows arbitrary html from the user, even when cleaned up by stripping away certain tags. This is exactly why tools like [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and [BBcode](http://www.bbcode.org/) exist. Why look, even StackOverflow is using similar.

The road you are considering traveling down is littered with 10,000 exploited web sites.

Answer (score 0):

You're lost when will allow your user do set HTML on your page, there a re wide range of possibilities like onmouseover"myEvilJS" or

Answer (score -1):

Minimum you must convert this symbols.

& -> &amp;

< -> &lt;

> -> &gt;

“ -> &quot;

‘ -> &#x27;

/ -> &#x2F;

Comment: No, I need to allow general HTML tags to let them render whatever they want, except XSS capable tags.

Comment: I think you got that wrong, this would escape and display the HTML source.